# Laravel Method Swift_Message::__toString() must not throw an exception

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

I'm sending email with mailgun when I remove the attachment it work fine PHP version here is `5.5.36` whereas on another server where PHP version is `5.5.9` it work fine with attachment.

```
$mail = Mail::send('emails.adviser', ['adviser' => $adviser , 'data' => $data , 'email_content' =>  $email_content ] , function ($message) use ($data, $adviser)   {
    $message->from($adviser->email, $adviser->first_name .' ' . $adviser->last_name);
    $message->to( $data['email'] )->subject('Re: Warburg Capital Group')->attach( asset('attachment/warburg_brochure.pdf'));
});
```

Comment: What exception is it throwing?

Comment: it only give this error `FatalErrorException in MailgunTransport.php line 0:
Method Swift_Message::__toString() must not throw an exception`

Comment: Can you verify the contents of `$data` and `$adviser`? Basically, that error means it tried to access a property of a member object (or array) that did not exist. This invoked an exception, and `__toString()` cannot be called on that exception. It's misleading and wonky, but at least you know now.

Comment: if i remove this `->attach( asset('attachment/warburg_brochure.pdf')` then it is working so $data and $adviser is fine